# HIBERNATE AND HSQLDB - Works on PC - Error on Linux

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I've created a test application on my PC to get familiar with Hibernate on an HSQLDB.

I made an executable JAR and moved the application on to a Linux VM.  When I run the same program after set up, my HSQLDB throws the following message when I try to run the test app:

A pre-9.0 client attemtped to connect.  We rejected them.

This occurs when I try to create the SessionFactory.

Any idea what I'm over looking?

Thanks,

Trev

Comment: `I made an executable JAR and moved the application on to a Linux VM` What is the structure of this jar? What version of HSQLDB are you using? Where is the database? What is the database connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message indicates that you are using the client / server mode. The server is running the HSQLDB 2.0 jar, but the client is using an earlier jar, probably version 1.8.

In order to use HSQLDB 2.0 with Hibernate, you should use the HSQLDB snapshot jar from http://hsqldb.org/support/ (both on the client and server) together with the latest Hibernate version 3.5.6.